# Ionic2: From one of the pages, what is the proper `src` URL to display an image?

Tags: ionic2

From one of the pages, what is the proper src URL to display an image located in **www/assets/images/image.jpg**?

```
<!-- Invalid Path -->
<ion-img width="80" height="80" src="assets/images/image.jpg"></ion-img>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use path:

`src="./assets/images/image.jpg`

It needs to be relative

Answer (score 1):

It will be assets/images/image.jpg.

I would recommend you to put you images in src folder since when you build app it will be copied into www folder.

Comment: Good info. Thanks.